# Javascript link tracking script + Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a link tracking script. It should work like Google Analytics only it should make posts to our own server. I'm using jQuery for this. The code i have written so far is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var opts;

jQuery.fn.trackAllLinks = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.fn.trackAllLinks.defaults, settings);
    opts = settings;

    function track() {
        href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var trackImage = new Image(1, 1);
        trackImage.src = opts.linkredirector + '?eurl=' + jQuery.URLEncode(href) + '&rnd=' + new Date().getTime() + '&title=trackerimage.gif';
        trackImage.onload = function() { 
            trackImage.onload = null; 
            doNothing(); 
        }
        delay(300);
        return true;
    };

    function delay(mseconds) {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var endTime = currentTime.getTime() + mseconds;
        while (currentTime.getTime() < endTime) {
            currentTime = new Date();
        }
    }

    function doNothing() { 
    }

    if(jQuery(this).is("a")) {
        jQuery(this).click(track);
    }

    jQuery(this).find("a").click(track);

};

jQuery.fn.trackAllLinks.defaults = {
    linkredirector : '__url_to_post_on__'
};

});
```

It works fine in all browsers except Safari. When i'm using a mailto link or an anchor it works but when i'm linking to another page it doesn't work. I have been testing a lot of different implementations and i can't get it to work. Any of you have an idea what i'm missing? I have tried to understand how Google Analytics works and as far as i can see it does the same. When i use WireShark to monitor my network i see that the image of Google is being requested but that my image isn't.

greets,
Daan

Comment: It likely doesn't make much difference, but is this issue in Safari on Windows? or on the Mac?

Comment: I've tested it in both version and both of them give the same problem. In Safari on mac i was able to debug the javascript and it is correctly executed .. it's just like the image isn't loaded in time, because after the click you'll be on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

This is random, but you might try adding a randomized parameter in the query string (both the name & value), like:

```
Math.random(0, 1000) + '=' + Math.random(0, 1000)
```

I've had to do that in the past to get Safari to register a dynamically loaded resource.
(I see you have `&rnd=` already, but maybe try randomizing the name, too?)